# How to get data through asp.net core api call using html and jquery?

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to post data in the Mssql Database using Asp.netCore Api and Html Form. I have Added This script to post data.**but All the values are coming null**

Jquery script in Html File

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var valdata = $("#formData").serialize();  
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnsubmit").click(function (e) {
                let formData = {};
                $("#formData").serializeArray().map((x) => { formData[x.name] = x.value; });
 $.ajax({
                    url: "https://localhost:44389/Register",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: valdata,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    failure: function (data) {
                        alert("Failure: " + data);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("Error: " + data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

.net Core Api

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("Register")]
        public void RegisterExecute([FromBody]CustmRegistration Register)
        {
            try
            {
                userInterface.InsertCustomer(Register);
               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Sharad Kulshrestha, any update? Did my answer help you resolve your issue? –

Answer (score 1):

1.When you use `.serialize()`, it generates the data in a `query string` format which needs to be sent using the default contentType which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, not as JSON. Either remove the contentType option or specify `contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` can work.

2.Also you need move the `serialize` method into onclick event.

3.Be sure change `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]`.

Here is a whole working demo:

View:

```
@model CustmRegistration 
<form id="formData">
       <!--more code-->
       <input type="button" id="btnsubmit"value="create" />                 
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnsubmit").click(function (e) {
                var valdata = $("#formData").serialize();  //move to here...                
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/home/Register",
                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: valdata,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    failure: function (data) {
                        alert("Failure: " + data);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("Error: " + data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Register")]
public void RegisterExecute([FromForm]CustmRegistration Register)   
{ //...}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but All the values are coming null

Where are these values null? my suggestion is to start debugging a bit more thoroughly.

- Have you tried your api function trough postman or a tool likewise?
- Settting breakpoints can be nice to look into your program's data at runtime.
- if these values are null in your database it would be nice to see what `userInterface.InsertCustomer(Register);` does.
- Once you know if your .net part is working start debugging your ajaxc call. take a look at the network section of the developer tools form the browser you are using.

If you have collected more data, people can help you more easelly.